# Buoyancy of a balloon filled with heated water vapor

Tags: buoyancy, gas

Why not fill the balloons not with heated air, but with heated water vapor, for example, placing a container of water between the burner and the neck of the ball? Obvious advantage: water vapor is about 1.7 times lighter than air.

**EDITE**
Let me reformulate the question: will a balloon rise in the air if instead of a burner we place a vessel with boiling water at the neck of the balloon?

Comment: Because it is harder to produce than hot air? Because it will condense? Because it takes a lot of energy to evaporate the water?  You should be more specific.

Comment: I don’t think it’s harder, especially since the air in the balloon heats up to a temperature of about 100 degrees Celsius, which will provide boiling water in the container. Condensate will drain back into the container if the shell material of the ball made of  not wetted material.

Comment: The amount of heat to just evaporate the water is very high. Not to mention the high heat capacity.  I suggest you do the exercise to calculate how much energy is needed to get a certain volume of water vapor as opposed to air starting at (say) 20 Celsius. And if the water condenses, all that vaporization energy is lost, and needs to be put into the system again.  Again, why don't you go ahead and do the rough calculation, and if you find it performs comparably/better, we continue the discussion?

Comment: If the steam could be relatively sealed then maybe. But hard to do with pressure changes with altitude. Also, 100C steam causes burns far faster than 100C air. On a related note, in a hot dry desert a sealed toy plastic (not pressurized) balloon of air with 100% humidity may barely be able to float even without solar heating.

Comment: @Kevin Kostlan, Apparently, we may not seal it, but simply placing a vessel of water in its neck

Comment: The ancient Iranians apparently used this effect to cool their homes in hot, arid areas (Cold, humid air flows from the bottom of the well with cold water up to the home, as it is lighter than hot, dry air outside

Answer (score 1):

Obvious disadvantage: you need to carry your container of water for a steam balloon (heating a hermetically sealed balloon has its own share of problems), whereas there is always enough air for a hot-air balloon.

Comment: I agree, we cannot collect all the condensate back, but we have a huge advantage in buoyancy: the mass of a balloon filled with water vapor instead of air heated to 100 degrees Celsius should be more than 2 times (!) less,

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist : and you lose this advantage if you have to replace the water vapor in the balloon just once during the flight.

Comment: do you remember that a steam locomotive is constantly connected with a tender that transports  fuel  and water? :)

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist : if this is not just a joke, I don't understand how this is relevant.

Comment: Of course, this is a joke, the main problem, as I see it: We have two processes - the production of water vapor by a point source of heat and the condensation of this vapor on a large surface of the shell of the ball. The balance of these two processes determines the resulting mass of water vapor, which in turn determines buoyancy. The critical condition, it seems to me, is not the consumption of water, but the power of the heating source to obtain a sufficiently high steam production rate.